# Pass all elements in existing array to xargs

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal, xargs

I am trying to pass an array of file paths to `xargs` to move them all to a new location. My script is currently working as follows:

```
FILES=( /path/to/files/*identifier* )
if [ -f ${FILES[0]} ]
  then
    mv ${FILES[@]} /path/to/destination
fi
```

The reason for having FILES as a array was because the `if [ -f /path/to/files/*identifier* ]` fails if the wildcard search returns multiple files. Only the first file is checked, because the move will be executed if any files exist.

I want to replace `mv ${FILES[@]} /path/to/destination` with a line that passes `${FILES[@]}` to `xargs` to move each file. I need to use `xargs` as I expect to have enough files to overload a single `mv`. Through research I have only been able to find the methods of moving files that I already know which search for the files again.

```
#Method 1
ls /path/to/files/*identifier* | xargs -i mv '{}' /path/to/destination

#Method 2
find /path/to/files/*identifier* | xargs -i mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

#### Is there a way to can pass all elements in an existing array `${FILES[@]}` to `xargs`?

Below are methods I've tried and their errors.

**Attempt 1**:

```
echo ${FILES[@]} | xargs -i mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

Error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/path/to/files/file1.zip /path/to/files/file2.zip /path/to/files/file3.zip /path/to/files/file4.zip': No such file or directory
```

**Attempt 2**:
I wasn't sure if `xargs` can be executed directly or not.

```
xargs -i mv ${FILES[@]} /path/to/destination
```

Error:
No error message was output, but it hung after that line until I stopped it manually.

### Edit: Find works

I tried the following and it moved all the files. Is this the best way to do it? And is it moving the files one by one, so the terminal is not overloaded?

```
find ${FILES[@]} | xargs -i mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

### Edit 2:

For future reference, I tested the accepted answer method versus the method in my first edit using `time()`. After running both methods 4 times, my method had an average of 0.659s and the accepted answer was 0.667s. So neither method works any faster than the other.

Comment: Why don't you just do `mv /path/to/files/*identifier* /path/to/destination`?

Comment: The wildcard result will often return thousands of files that `mv` can't handle. As I said in the question, "I need to use `xargs` as I expect to have enough files to overload a single `mv`"

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed that part. Then I guess the best is to use `find . -name "..." -exec mv {} \;` having the pattern of the file in the `name`.

Comment: `find -exec` will call mv once for each file. That could be slow.

Comment: "find -exec will call mv once for each file." -- not if you use the `{} +` option. But anyway, the actual topic of this question was: how to avoid the redundant invocation of `find`, `ls` etc. when you already possess a list of file paths.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you do

```
echo ${FILES[@]} | xargs -I {} mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

xargs treats the entire line as a singe argument. You should split each element of the array to a new line, and then `xargs` should work as expected:

```
printf "%s\n" "${FILES[@]}" | xargs -I {} mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

Or if your filenames can contain newlines, you can do

```
printf "%s\0" "${FILES[@]}" | xargs -0 -I {} mv '{}' /path/to/destination
```

Comment: Why doesn't `printf "%s " "${FILES[@]}" | xargs -i mv '{}' /path/to/destination` work? Space instead of `\n`, `mv` accepts several files for moving to a directory.

Comment: @Roland: `mv` does accept multiple arguments, but with your command you pass a *single* argument (including spaces). It looks like `-i` and `-I` cause `-L 1` to be set, so you can only get one item per invocation. There are some workarounds available however, if you look at this question for example: https://superuser.com/a/705651/301351